# Make exactly the same post from C# as Form.Submit()

Tags: c#, .net, forms, submit, http-post

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>NOVA</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="file.com/">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>dataType</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dataType" value="xml"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>actionType</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="actionType" value="query"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>accountid</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="accountid" value="121758"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>checksum</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="file" value="123"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="text-align:right"><input type="submit" value="send"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I've tried.

```
string xml = @"<Array><dataType>xml</dataType><actionType>query</actionType><accountid>121758</accountid><file>" + "123" + "</file></Array>";
WebRequest req = null;
WebResponse rsp = null;

string uri = "https://file.com/";
req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "text/xml";
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
writer.WriteLine(xml);
writer.Close();
rsp = req.GetResponse();
```

but this is not the same. I want exactly the same as form.submit();

Comment: _"This is what I've tried."_ - so, what happened? What do you expect to happen? What have you tried exactly, apart from guessing some XML format that is not being sent by the browser? Please take a look at [HTTP request with post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post).

Comment: What do you expect as my answer for you question?.. 
It is not the same as submitting the form!!! Read the question's title

Comment: I expect you to show what you want to happen. You can't just dump your code and say _"This don't work"_. If you take a look using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for example, you'll see your form gets posted with `dataType=xml&actionType=query&accountid=121758&file=123`, not some arbitrary XML format. Calling `form.submit()` from JavaScript won't change this. So I guess the accepted answer doesn't do what you say you want it to do, it doesn't do the same as `form.submit()` but it simply posts `dataType=xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're code is more complicated than needed. It's also incorrect. For example, the `ContentType` should be `multipart/form-data`, not `text/xml`.

Instead, use a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in conjunction with a [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx):

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    NameValueCollection formValues = new NameValueCollection();
    formValues.Add("dataType", "xml");
    client.UploadValues("http://www.somesite.com/SomePage.aspx", formValues);
}
```

If you need to capture the response as well, use this method:

```
byte[] response = null;

using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    NameValueCollection formValues = new NameValueCollection();
    formValues.Add("dataType", "xml");
    response = client.UploadValues("http://www.somesite.com/SomePage.aspx", formValues);
}
```